# ANTS memory profiler -- can the profiler be attached to a service built in release?

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-management, service

Is there a way to attach ANTS to a service, particularly one where the build is release instead of debug?

Ideally I'd like to be able to generate a dump then replay it later through the very pleasant ANTS UI.  Can ANTS do this? If not are there tools that can?

Comment: The VS profiler can do this. For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255414.aspx

Comment: The link's broken, but I presume you are talking about Intellitrace.  I, unfortunately do not have the $4,000 version of VS2010 :(

Comment: The VS profiler comes with Premium rather than Ultimate (which comes with Intellitrace) but, yeah, it's not free :( CLR Profiler is free and you can attach it to a process: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx

Comment: Ah, I did not realize this.  But alas I have only Professional.  I'm hoping VS 11 all versions ship with IntelliTrace.  I'm going check out the free one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is .Net 4 then you can most certainly profile it by attaching to the process. You are also able to do this for a release build of the service. If needed, make sure to show the processes from all the users - then refresh the list to make sure you see your service in the list.

When attaching to a .Net4 process with the memory profiler you will need to disable concurrent Garbage collection, instructions on how to do this are [here](http://www.red-gate.com/SupportCenter/content/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.4/amp_attachtoprocess).

As long as you have disabled the concurrent collection, just attach to the .Net4 process for the service and interact with it as you need to, while taking snapshots of the memory when the application is in the desired state. 
You are also able to automate the taking of snapshots from code in your application by using the API exposed by the Memory Profiler, this is explained [here](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.4/amp_snapshot_api).

Comment: Upvote/solved.  This is good stuff.  Am I going to take a hit by disabling concurrent garbage collection?

Comment: [link](http://www.red-gate.com/SupportCenter/content/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.4/amp_attachtoprocess): While concurrent garbage collections are disabled, your application will run faster but may pause occasionally to allow garbage collections to take place.
While concurrent garbage collections are disabled, the total memory footprint of your application is fractionally increased. This is because the concurrent garbage collector would normally build a graph of unreachable objects on the other thread. This difference should not be significant enough to alter the results shown by ANTS